# Stopping Camera Spin in Gone Home?

Tags: gone-home

When I start Gone Home, the menus are continuously scrolled from left to right. Starting the game makes the camera constantly look up and rotate around. Why? How can this be stopped?

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by [vJoy](http://vjoystick.sourceforge.net/site/), a joystick emulator.

Constant movement doesn't just happen in Gone Home (error reported [here](http://steamcommunity.com/app/232430/discussions/1/540744935513268940/)), but also in, for example, [Electronic Super Joy](http://steamcommunity.com/app/244870/discussions/0/648811852547252211/?insideModal=1).

[Removing](http://vjoystick.sourceforge.net/site/index.php/77-vjoy/102-removing-vjoy) or disabling vJoy solves the issue.

## Disabling vJoy

The process is similar to removing vJoy.

1. Start `devmgmt.msc`.
2. **View**: **Devices by Connection**.
3. Right-click on **vJoy Device**.
4. Select **Disable**.